# How to use objects from a later version of Sencha ExtJS?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

So I am working on a project using Sencha ExtJS 4.1.0 but I need to use some methods that are not present on this version, but they are on version 4.2.1.

Specifically, I am looking to use the Ext.form.field.ComboBox class, and methods such as setMargin.

Is it safe and possible to just replace the class I need on my ExtJS folder with the new one?

Thanks!

Comment: you can override ComboBoxClass add the setMargin method. It would be better inthat way than replacing whole class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you cannot just take a class (file) from a newer version and replace with it the corresponding class in the older version. It is very likely that methods were not only added but some may be removed, still required by the older version, signatures (arguments with which to call methods) may have changed, html markup could also be changed, etc.

What you can do is to study the method in new class and add it manually to the existing one in the form of an extension or override.

Also, if you find that you need the new functionality more and more, it is perhaps the time to upgrade the whole app to the new, or newer, Ext version.